# How to Code a Loan (Payment) Estimator in HTML?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am setting up a new website through godaddy.com and am having the hardest time trying to code up the calculator for customers to estimate their payments (Must Include: Loan Amount, Loan Length in Months, Interest rate, and Monthly Payment). The Monthly payment is what I am having trouble calculating because of code placement. Again, i am working with godaddy.com and just need an HTML code for this payment estimator.

I have tried inspecting multiple pages to see what I can get off of them, I have used an html generator, and have contacted several people in my are with no hope.

This is the code I currently have:

```
<html><div class="wpb_wrapper"><center><form method="POST" name="calc">
<table border="0" width="60%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="50%">Data Entry</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F7F7F7">Loan Amount</td>
<td align="right" bgcolor="#F7F7F7">$<input id="amount" max="100000000" min="1" name="loan" size="10" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F7F7F7">Loan Length in Months</td>
<td align="right" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><input name=" months" size="10" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F7F7F7">Interest Rate</td>
<td align="right" bgcolor="#F7F7F7">%<input max="10000000" min="1" name="rate" size="10" type="text" value="10" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F7F7F7">Monthly Payment</td>
<td align="right" bgcolor="#F7F7F7"><em>Calculated</em> <input name="pay" size="10" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="button" value="Calculate" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<p><span style="font-size: xx-small;"> "Enter only numeric values (no commas), using decimal points where needed." <br /> "Non-numeric values will cause errors." </span></p>
  </center></div></html>
```

No error messages, it just won't let me calculate the monthly payment.

Comment: HTML alone won't do any calculations, you need either JavaScript or some server side code to do any calculations.

Comment: Do you know how to put this into JavaScript?

Comment: You don't "put something into javascript", see the answer I will be posting

Comment: Your inputs need Id's, you then fetch the value of said inputs via their id using javascript and then use those values to do your calculation and maybe set another inputs value to the result of said calculation. I would suggest you start learning javascript: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/javascript/

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a pure HTML code, which cannot do any calculation by itself.

However, if all you want is a simple loan calculator, you don't have to code one from scratch. There are free ready-to-use calculators available that can be embedded in to your HTML code.

**Solution 1: Using an HTML embed code.**

Here's one such free calculator I found from https://www.mortgagecalculator.biz/c/free3.php  :

Paste this in your html code:

```
<div style="width:185px; text-align:center;">
    <p style="text-align:center;">
       <a href="https://www.mortgagecalculator.biz" target="_blank">
           <img src="https://www.mortgagecalculator.biz/img/mlogo.gif" border="0" alt="Mortgage Calculator.biz."/>
       </a><br/>
       <iframe src="https://www.mortgagecalculator.biz/c/variables.php?loan=258678&rate=4.1&years=30" frameborder="0" width="185px" height="240px" scrolling="no"></iframe><br/>
       <a href="https://www.mortgagecalculator.biz/c/free.php" target="_blank"><font size="1" color="#000000">HTML Mortgage Calculators</font></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

The downside of using an embed code is it relies on an external site for the calculator. If that site goes down, so does your calculator.

**Solution 2: Integrating code in the html file:**

The better alternative is to integrate the actual calculator code on your HTML file.  Try looking for a free code online, that can be used with the author's permission.

Here is something for your reference: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut155.shtml

**PS: Posting this as an answer since my current reputation (11) doesn't let me comment.**

Answer (score -2):

HTML alone can't do calculations. To do this, you will need to learn javascript (there are many good tutorials on the web).

After you learn javascript, and you know how to create functions and change the content of elements, you can do these calculations.

To run a javascript function when a button is clicked, write this:

```
<button onclick="function();">Button text</button>
```